# ClickOnce giving strange errors on startup

Tags: clickonce

I have a small ClickOnce application, which I deployed. I'm noticing, on my machine, that I'm getting strange startup errors, like "Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access this item." Try to run it as administrator, it doesn't even begin loading. Access the exe manually, all works fine. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

EDIT: Tried reinstalling, same error.

EDIT2: Got an error xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Answers Version="1.0">
    <Interaction ID="IT_LaunchMethod">
        <Value>ContextMenu</Value>
    </Interaction>
    <Interaction ID="IT_SelectProgram">
        <Value>NotListed</Value>
    </Interaction>
    <Interaction ID="IT_BrowseForFile">
        <Value>C:\Users\MyUserPath\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\RN7Y3C3O.4KQ\P64V6E15.NWW\somelongfoldername\MyFile.exe</Value>
    </Interaction>
</Answers>
```

Any idea what this means?

EDIT3: Just in before anyone says that the path is wrong: I haven't modified anything, I'm trying to let ClickOnce do its job. If the path is wrong, it's ClickOnce's fault, as all I did was install it, and then try to open it.

Comment: Are you starting the app from the start menu shortcut? Right click the shortcut and select properties to see the target under the security tab and make sure it is a valid path. If you have Updating enabled, then make sure this path is available also. Right click the proj file and inspect the properties of the project for any incorrect or missing addresses under the delpoy(?) tab.

Comment: They're all fine. But thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, all it was was my antivirus getting all worked up. Bad heuristics made it block it, however, it didn't tell me. I only found out because I got it to work when I changed my antivirus. Very odd...

Comment: Happened to me to day. Caused by Avast Free Anti-Virus silent blocking

Comment: I know this is old, but just wanted to add that this also happened to me due to a Windows Security pop-up: "These files might be harmful to your computer." The pop-up wasn't shown when the app was started normally, but rather only when I tried to copy files FROM the publish location onto my local desktop; however, the security warning that requires an "OK" response from the user was interpreted by the .NET runtime as an "access denied" error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain where exactly you're seeing the XML above? I've never seen anything like that before. So when are you seeing the error? When the user installs it, does it work the first time, or is it just on subsequent times that it doesn't work?

What is your installation URL? Is it published to a web server, or to a file share and the user doesn't have access to it? Or are you doing something completely different like copying the deployment to the user's machine and installing it that way?

Comment: I saw it after it gave me some startup errors, it linked me to it. It,doesn't work the first time. It's deployed to a Dropbox public folder. And this only happens to me. It works fine on a few other computers.

Comment: If the problem happens at startup, and not when installing the application, then it is not a ClickOnce issue, it is a bug in your application. Try putting in some trace logging or messagebox statements to figure out exactly where it's failing. It could be that you don't have permissions to access some file that you're trying to access.

Comment: I thought that too. So I wrapped Main in a try catch. Nothing. It wont run.